LWC show specific Pickist value on load
I have an LWC where I am using the wire to grab the picklist values
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
      recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
      TypeOptionsWrapper({ data }) {
        if (data) {
          thisTypeOptions = data.values;
      }
    }

   <lightning-combobox name="Type__c" label="Type" value={rowData.Type__c} options={TypeOptions} onchange={handleChange} required></lightning-combobox>

This works well.  My question is how can I show a specific value as selected in the picklist when the LWC loads.

@Phuc
@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
   typeOptions;

//For default value

<template if:true={typeOptions.data}>
<lightning-combobox name="Type__c" label="Type" value={typeOptions.data.defaultValue.label} options={typeOptions.data.values} onchange={handleChange} required></lightning-combobox>

//For Specific value
@wire(getPicklistValues, {
      recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
      TypeOptionsWrapper({ data }) {
        if (data) {
          thisTypeOptions = data.values;
          this.rowData.Type__c = data.values[0].label;//In value attribute You can specify any index You want for all templates
      }
    }




If you know the value then you can hardcode it. But it is not preferrable. Yet there is a way to get the default picklist value, you can set that if you need. Check this link to get default picklist in apex. Let me know if it is still not solved or didn't satisfy your requirement.

thank you for the response.  The value I want to set will not be the default value.  I will have multiple template section in the LWC.  Inside each template I want to show a specific value in the picklist.  So each template section will show the picklist field with a different value showing.  Ideally I would rather not hardcode as you stated but if I had to what does the syntax look like?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/documentation -- Check here, at first documentation specification they used example with default value hardcoded. you can populate value variable with required value. Please mark this as best answer if your query is solved, or let me know what you need.
